# Query: detect if element with specific data attr has already been cloned

Tags: jquery, clone, each

```
$(".sect-tasklist li.is-running").each(function(){

    var $this = $(this),
        taskID = $(this).data("task-id");
    
    if ( /*if elem has already been cloned*/ ) {
        console.log("already cloned, don't clone it again");
    } else {
        $(this).clone().appendTo(".helper-timers");
    }

});
```

Each task (li.is-running) has it's own unique ID applied in the data-task-id attribute. The code should duplicate each task into a temporary div (.helper-timers), however if a task has already been cloned and exists inside .helper-timers, it obviously doesn't need to be duplicated again.

---

#### Solved

**To anyone wondering, I managed to solve it like this.**

```
(function(){
    jQuery.fn.cloneRunningTimers = function() {
        $(".sect-tasklist li.is-running").each(function(){
            var $this = $(this),
            taskID = $this.data("task-id");
            
            if ( $(".helper-timers li.task-id-" + taskID).length ) { // if exists
                // already cloned, don't clone again
            } else { // if doesn't exist
                $this.clone().appendTo(".helper-timers"); // clone
            }
        }); 
    }; // fn cloneRunningTasks
})();
```

Then part of my function for getting tasks includes this:

```
$(".helper-timers li").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
    taskID = $this.data("task-id");
    
    if ( $(".sect-tasklist li.task-id-" + taskID).length ) { // if exists it task list
        $this.remove(); // delete it from helper list
    }
});
```

Which as far as I can tell, makes sure that the same task is never in both places at once.

Comment: can u provide markup or make fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You could create an external reference of task IDs that have been cloned like so:

```
var alreadyCloned = [];
$(".sect-tasklist li.is-running").each(function(){

    var $this = $(this),
        taskID = $(this).data("task-id");

    if ( $.inArray(taskID, alreadyCloned) > -1 ) {
        console.log("already cloned, don't clone it again");
    } else {
        alreadyCloned.push(taskID);
        $this.clone().appendTo(".helper-timers");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may tag the elements that have been processed (cloned) already by using the `data` function of `jquery`.

For example:

```
if ($this.data('cloned')) {
    console.log("already cloned, don't clone it again");
} else {
    $this.data('cloned', true);
    $this.clone().appendTo(".helper-timers");
}
```

`$this.data('cloned')` will return the value for the data field `cloned`, `$this.data('cloned', true)` will set the data field to `true`. (Note: `cloned` is an arbitrary name, you can use any name you like.)

Comment: The problem is that the .is-running list constantly changes (its overwritten with ajax), so even if I were to add "cloned" to an item, it wouldn't be there when i need it. I was thinking i could make use of the already existing data-task-id attr, since that contains a unique number for each task. Then, when it is duplicated, to somehow use jquery to detect whether just one or two instances of that number existed on the page. Thoughts on this?